# JavaScript Misbehaviour

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to send my form data to an .php file with AJAX but JS is misbehaving 
, what actually happens is that when i leave the input fields empty every thing works fine (i.e. the php program executes and make changes in my database as expected) but when i fill form data , like when i fill name , email ,password my client side page refreshes and php file dosent gets executed .

Sorry for any grammatical mistakes .

I appreciate any help from anyone !

Thanks alot !

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form_signup");
var formdata = new FormData(form);

$('#form_signup').on('submit', function(ev) {
  console.log(formdata);
  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "./process_php/Signup1.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: "POST",


    success: function(response) {
      console.log("done" + response);
    }

  });
  return false;

});
```

```css
<?php 
if (!isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
 die();
}
$username = "temp_username";
$email = "temp_email";
$password = "temp_password";
$sqlconnection = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
$insertstatement = "INSERT INTO new_users (Name , Email , Password , Subscriber ) VALUES ('$username' , '$email' , '$password' , 'Normal' ) ";
if ($sqlconnection->query($insertstatement) === TRUE) {       //if entered into db successfully
    echo "DONE";
}else {

 //run js to inform
 }

?>
```

```html
<!--I have loaded jquery and also my external js file-->

<form class="font1" id="form_signup">
  <!-- main content , signup form -->
  <h2 id="form_name" class="font1">LOGIN</h2>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" minlength="3" autofocus id="username"><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" minlength="10"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" minlength="8"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: Well for starters, `var formdata = new FormData(form);` should be inside your submit handler - otherwise, you are just capturing the state the form had when the page loaded, but before the user has input anything.

Comment: What's the purpose of `formdata`? You're setting it before the user submits the form, you're logging it, but you're not actually sending it to the server.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Actually when i try to receive data in my php file i get an error message (undefined index)

Comment: Why are you setting contentType to false ?

Comment: @AntoineGautrain That's almost certainly the problem. That setting is only appropriate when sending `FormData`, not when using `.serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem with `$('form').serialize()`. Here `form` is not the one same as `var form = document.getElementById("form_signup");`

```
$('#form_signup').on('submit', function(ev) {
  console.log(formdata);
  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "./process_php/Signup1.php",
    data:  $('#form_signup').serialize(),
    // rest of the code
```

Comment: While this is better code, it would only be a problem if he has multiple forms on the page.

Comment: I thought `$('#form_signup')` will pick up only specific form.

Comment: `$('form').serialize()` will serialize the first form on the page. If there's only one form, it's the same as `$(this)` or `$('#form_signup')`

Comment: So your answer would only be the solution if he has multiple forms and he's trying to submit the form that isn't first.